# Real World Haskell code not compiling?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to compile some code in Real World Haskell - Chapter 24. LineCount.hs.

**I have not made any changes to the code.**

However, when I do:

```
ghc -O2 --make -threaded LineCount.hs
```

(as instructed in the book), I get the message:

```
MapReduce.hs:6:7: Not in scope: `rnf'
```

What might I be doing wrong?

A quick search showed up that there was some trouble with the packages parallel and strict-concurrency in the past, and that reinstalling them would fix the issue. However, I tried that and it didn't work. Moreover, it is noted there that that issue was fixed sometime in 2010:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/happs/gOieP4xfpNc/nrasm842JlUJ

Note: I get various other errors when compiling other files in the same chapter. For example, on compiling Strat.hs I get: Module `Control.Parallel.Strategies' does not export`parZipWith'. On compiling LineChunks.hs I get: Module `Control.Parallel.Strategies' does not export`rnf'.

Honestly, as a novice Haskell programmer I expected to run into trouble once I started modifying code - but I didn't expect to have trouble with code from a book!

Comment: You might need `Control.DeepSeq` http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=rnf

Comment: I just installed that, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: If @Clark didn't answer your question, please post the code in question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function is no longer called `rnf`. It's called `rdeepseq` now. Just replace it. :)

You can find the contents of the `parallel` package online by googling "control parallel strategies hackage", or clicking [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.0.3).

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot! That was the first Haskell code I've ever compiled and it couldn't be a worse start. :P

Comment: No problem! Haskell can be a lot of fun. Keep it up!

Comment: Is there a RWH errata page somewhere? The mtl 1.x -> 2.0 transition threw me off the tracks, for some time.

Comment: @yatima2975 Not any official errata, but there's this SO question and its corresponding answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23727768/126014 I've found it helpful from time to time.